# Consistency and Partition-Tolerance in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

As I am new to elasticsearch using [elasticsearch version 7.4] and with a lot of studies it is not clear till now how much shards / Nodes are preferred in particular index.  As of now, I have configured 3 shards and 2 replicas with 3 Nodes(each having 8GB RAM, 500GB HDD). and having 55GB of Data in One Index. 
So I need your views/suggestions in the following points.

1. Is above given no of shards, Nodes, replicas is sufficient.
2. For CAP theorem I will prefer CP i.e: Consistency and Partition-tolerance for this in 3 Node cluster

   - For Consistency configured write_consistency=all
   - For Partition-tolerance set master-eligible node to (N/2) + 1 in my case it is 3.

Answer (score 0):

I can hopefully give you some useful advice from my time running Elasticsearch clusters :)

1)

Shards: See [this blog post for more information](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-many-shards-should-i-have-in-my-elasticsearch-cluster), but your average shard will be `55gb/3 = 18gb` which is a good shard size (in my experience it's best to keep 
shards between `5gb-25gb`, the ES docs recommend this as well).

Replicas: 2 replicas is my go-to for a good balance between failure tolerance and performance, so this is good.

Nodes: Those 3 nodes should be sufficient, and you won't need that much disk. With 2 replicas you'll have roughly `55gb * 3 = 165gb` of data stored (could be more depending on your mapping) across `1500gb` of hard drive, so perhaps you could save some money by using nodes with `100gb` disks.

2)

For partition tolerance I might suggest setting `write_consistency=quorum`. That way, even if you lose a node and therefore 1 replica shard you'll still be able to write with 1 primary and 1 replica left. Otherwise, you'd need to reboot/recreate that node to start writing again. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-index_.html#index-consistency for more details.

Master-eligible: Yes I recommend a minimum of 3 master nodes, so you'll want to set all 3 of these nodes to be master and data nodes.